# How to pass a custom SSLContext with Axis Client to call SOAP service?

Tags: java, soap, jboss, axis, soap-client

I am using Axis-1.4 to call a SOAP service. It was working till wsdl was hosted on http. As a part of security implmentation,now SOAP server has enabled access on https with Client certificate authentication.

I have created one custom keystore of type JKS and imported the certificate chain into it with alias "myalias". To test the client certificate, I have tested with HttpsURLConnection implementation as below and SOAP server is able to recieve client certificate -

HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

But I am not able to send the Client certificate when used with Axis Client. Soap server returns with auth error 7104 No client certificate received.

Solution :
Create one SocketFactory like this :

```
public class MySocketFactory extends JSSESocketFactory implements SecureSocketFactory {
    public MySocketFactory(Hashtable attr){
        super(attr);
    }

    protected void initFactory() throws IOException {

        try {
            SSLContext context = getContext();
            this.sslFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof IOException) {
                throw (IOException) e;
            }
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
 protected SSLContext getContext() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
                    String  CERT_P = "changeit";

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory =KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore identityKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        FileInputStream identityKeyStoreFile = new FileInputStream(new File("Path to your jks"));
        identityKeyStore.load(identityKeyStoreFile, CERT_P.toCharArray());
        keyManagerFactory.init(identityKeyStore,CERT_P.toCharArray());
        log.debug("MySocketFactory -- Keystore loaded-");

        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),null, new SecureRandom());

            return sslContext;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Error creating context for SSLSocket.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

and then before calling to your binding port method add below code :
´´´
AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory", MySocketFactory.class.getCanonicalName());

´´´
This worked for me.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes..Create your SocketFactory class like below: I am trying to attach a file but I can not.. So I will update my question..

Comment: Thank you. I think this is pretty much exactly what I was after.